# Prevent graceless crash from occurring in application calling library via P/Invoke

Tags: c#, c++

I have a C# application `App A` that calls, via P/Invoke, a C++ (Qt) DLL `App B`. Let's assume I cannot, by any means, edit `App B`, but I know that `App B` is throwing an `Out of Memory Exception` under a set of conditions which I can replicate but not accurately test for before passing input from `App A` to `App B`. This exception does not pose any threat to `App A` and could be ignored if `App B` could be "reset" in some manner, but when `App B` crashes it calls `abort()` which in turn causes `App A`'s runtime to terminate.

How can I prevent `App B`'s inevitable, unpredictable, and generally mundane crash from impacting `App A`?

*Notes:*

- An implemented `UnhandledExceptionHandler` is ignored when this error is thrown.
- `App B` crashes due to a bug in QtWebkit which could feasibly be handled by `App B` via deleting the oversize object and returning null.
- `App A` does not report as out of memory and the machine has more than enough memory to perform the `App B`'s operation several times over, regardless of the bug, but this memory is apparently not allocated to `App B` for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the SIGABRT coming from the unmanaged code, but it's a little messy. It's possible it could be done completely in C#, but my method requires a C++/CLI assembly to make it work (at least it is all in one process).

Step 1: Create a C++/CLI Class Library project, in the *.h file put the following function

```
namespace ClassLibrary1 {

    public ref class Class1
    {
    public:
        static void callaborter();
    };
}
```

Step 2: in the cpp file put the following code:

```
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <csetjmp>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "ClassLibrary1.h"
#include "..\Win32Project1\Win32Project1.h"


#pragma managed(push, off) 
jmp_buf env;

void on_sigabrt (int signum)
{
    longjmp (env, 1);
}

void run()
{
    if (setjmp (env) == 0) {
            signal(SIGABRT, &on_sigabrt);
            fnWin32Project1();
    }
    else {
            std::cout << "aborted\n";
    }
}

#pragma managed(pop)

void ClassLibrary1::Class1::callaborter()
{
    run();
}
```

I left the names of my classlibrary and class as default, and my aborting function is call fnWinProject1(). You will need to link the offending DLL directly to this project (just like it's in C++)

In your C# class, include a reference to the C++/CLI assembly and call the "callaborter" method.

The code in run will setup a catcher for the SIGABRT (called by abort()) and process it in on_sigabrt(), which will cause the whole function to bail. You can then clean up and try again.

I will leave it as an exercise for the OP to choose useful names.

Note: In Debug you will still get the abort dialog, just press Ignore to continue. In Release you will not see the dialog.

P.S. I should mention I built my response based on this stackoverflow question: [How to Handle SIGABRT signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934879/how-to-handle-sigabrt-signal)

Comment: I'll be implementing something similar to this, but within C# itself. Thanks for giving me a solid roadmap to work from!

Comment: @dambriso...you are welcome. Would you mind posting your C# version when done?

Comment: Will do. If I can, I'll add an additional answer to this question and tag you in it.

Answer (score 3):

You create a shim process whose only purpose is to load App B and use some IPC mechanism to communicate with App A. App A spawns the shim and if the shim crashes then App A takes the appropriate action (respawns, communicates an error to the user, etc.).

Comment: Not a bad option, although I'd prefer to do this within the context of a single app if possible. If nothing shows up that appropriately solves the problem in that manner, I'll accept this as the answer and implement it as the solution.