# How to get signal to catch SIGABRT

Tags: linux, windows, macos, c++11, sigabrt

I'm trying to catch a signal so I can make our program exit gracefully.  SIGABRT happens when we read a bad file, which we can't control.  This is a multi-platform program so we need something that works in windows, linux, and mac.

For some reason, when I add a signal_callback_handler like at [signal handling example](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Signals.html), and run the problem test in Windows, it's still coming up with the abort popup box like we had before.  How do I redirect before the popup for abort happens?  I want our program to exit gracefully.

```
//constructor
example::example(const string theString) 
{
   signal(SIGABRT, signal_callback_handler);
}

void example::signal_callback_handler(int sigNum)
{
   //want to handle gracefully here, but it's not getting caught
}

bool example::someMethod()
{
   FileHandle.openFile(problemDocument); //this openFile is where the SIGABRT happens
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934879/how-to-handle-sigabrt-signal) helpful for your question ?

Comment: I saw that example, and Antoine Matthys' example is very similar to mine.  I was looking at the example below it and had added a comment.  I still get the abort popup.  I want to exit the code my own way.  I realize the code can't continue as-is, but it's not hitting my breakpoint at all that I added in the handler.

Comment: Are you really allowed to pass a class method to `signal`?  I'd think that wouldn't work on many systems, since `example::signal_callback_handler()` is expecting to get passed its invisible `this` parameter, and the system signal handling code has no way of doing that.  So depending on calling conventions, it may get a totally messed up set of arguments.  What happens if you use a callback function which is not a method?

Comment: @Nate: presumably it's a static member function, or the compiler would have a fit.  Technically illegal per the C++ standard, IMO, because of the different language linkage, but in practice it should work (at least on Windows).

Comment: I did make it static.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is as documented.

From the [Visual Studio documentation for abort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k089yyh0.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> By default, when an app is built with the debug runtime library, the abort routine displays an error message **before** SIGABRT is raised. [...] To suppress the message, use _set_abort_behavior to clear the _WRITE_ABORT_MSG flag.

Comment: Thanks.  I realized that after I accept the abort box it actually hits my breakpoint in my signal handler method.  I think my team member is going to over-ride abort and we'll handle it as a regular exception instead of handling SIGABRT.

Comment: You could just use _set_abort_behavior if you preferred.  And do note that this only affects debug builds.

Comment: We need this for both debug and production