# OpenCV VideoWriter throws runtime error on full disk despite catching

Tags: opencv, c++11, visual-c++

I am using OpenCV 2.4.9 and Visual C++ 2017. I am writing video and for testing purposes tried to write a frame on a full disk.

I did

```
try {
    video_writer << frame;
} catch (cv::Exception& ex) {
    // Handle exception 
} catch (std::exception &e){
    // Handle exception
} catch (const std::runtime_error& error) {
    // Handle runtime error
}
```

on a full disk and hoped to be able to catch an exception. However I get a runtime error by the `Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library` stating "This application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way."

How would I catch this?

Comment: `...` (except that's a bad idea).  If you debug, what exception do you get - or is it actually an exception? It might not be.

Comment: I believe OpenCV sends sig_abrt using abort() function in that case. So no, you can't catch that exception.

Comment: Thank you both! Debugging showed a more specific error message: "abort() has been called".

Comment: Gald you found it. You can hook into the abort function if you want to do something specific. But you might not be able to do much by then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV uses `abort()` to notify about that issue. Since abort sends `SIGABRT` which is not a c++ exception, but rather a `signal` - you can't catch it within try catch block.

Also `SIGABRT` would cause your program to crash no matter what. You can still hook it and try to do some cleanups, but that won't stop program from terminating.

The only solution I met which would let you to work around that `SIGABRT` is described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934879/how-to-handle-sigabrt-signal)