# Handling libcurl abortion on timeout

Tags: c, libcurl

I am coding a daemon in C with a http client using libcurl.
I want it to be resilient to errors because the daemon will live in a risky environnement.

I added timeout control to not wait endlessly.

```
curl_easy_setopt(ezhandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300); //timeout after 5 minutes (use sigalarm)
curl_easy_setopt(ezhandle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2); //timeout after 2 seconds (use sigalarm)
curl_easy_setopt(ezhandle, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1); // Do not use signal
```

But when the request timeout (or other type of error) the lib is sending an abortion signal.
And my daemon is killed...
I got the error:

```
libcurl: (28) Connection timed out after 2000 milliseconds
Aborted
```

I tried handling the signal (with signal(6,mycallback)) but according to [How to Handle SIGABRT signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934879/how-to-handle-sigabrt-signal) it is not possible.

According to the documentations : https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html and https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.html it might cause a sigalarm.
I tried catching sigalarm with signal(13,myhandler) but it isn't triggered.

What would be the solution ?

PS: I believe threads might be a solution but I never used them and I would like to avoid the trouble.

This code is causing an error:

```
printf("%04X %04X %04X\n",LIBCURL_VERSION_MAJOR, LIBCURL_VERSION_MINOR, 
LIBCURL_VERSION_PATCH );
res = curl_easy_perform(ezhandle);
if(catchError(res,ezhandle,errbuf)==-1){
  printf("error \n");
  fclose(downloaded_file);
  //return -1;  // THIS IS THE ONLY CHANGE
};

if(CURLE_OK == res){}
if(ezhandle) {
  printf("ezhandle cleanup\n");
  curl_easy_cleanup(ezhandle);
}
printf("Does it execute this instruction ?"); // It stops before
return 0;
}
```

It gives the following result:

```
http://192.168.174.61/token
0007 0028 0000
libcurl: (28) Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes 
received
error
ezhandle cleanup
Aborted
```

This correct the problem:

```
if(catchError(res,ezhandle,errbuf)==-1){
printf("error \n");
fclose(downloaded_file);
return -1;  // THIS IS THE ONLY CHANGE
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my mistake,

In my function "catchError" i already cleanup ezhandle. Cleaning ezhandle twice in a row is provoking an abortion.

Comment: Did you just accept your own confused answer here? That's just wrong. curl_easy_cleanup()  should always be called if curl_easy_init() returned a handle. It will not "abort" in any circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

The comments in your code imply cURL would do a `SIGALRM` (value 13) signal, which is not `SIGABRT` (6) which you talk about later.

Have you tried `signal(SIGALRM, callback)`?