# What should mprobe return when it is passed a pointer to a freed block of memory?

Tags: c, malloc, free

The [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html) manual page for mcheck says that the MCHECK_FREE status means "The block was already freed." That would imply to me that the block was freed (at least) once. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8301089/8638338) seems to imply the same in the code example. However, the [Linux manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mcheck) says quite explicitly that MCHECK_FREE means "A block of memory was freed twice." I modified the code example from the above answer to make it slightly more descriptive:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mcheck.h>

void print_status(enum mcheck_status status)
{
    switch(status)
    {
        case MCHECK_DISABLED:
        printf("MCHECK_DISABLED\n");
        break;

        case MCHECK_OK:
        printf("MCHECK_OK\n");
        break;

        case MCHECK_HEAD:
        printf("MCHECK_HEAD\n");
        break;

        case MCHECK_TAIL:
        printf("MCHECK_TAIL\n");
        break;

        case MCHECK_FREE:
        printf("MCHECK_FREE\n");
        break;
    }
}

void no_op(enum mcheck_status status) {}

int main()
{
    mcheck(&no_op);

    void* f = malloc(4);

    print_status(mprobe(f));

    free(f);

    print_status(mprobe(f));

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code I get this output:

```
MCHECK_OK
MCHECK_HEAD
```

This means I'm clearly getting MCHECK_HEAD as a response when checking a freed block. Is this behaviour reliable? Is it reasonable to expect that the header of a block will always be clobbered when it is freed? Are there different implementations of mcheck/mprobe that will return MCHECK_FREE instead?

Comment: gcc --version -> gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0, ldd --version -> ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.32-0ubuntu3) 2.32

Comment: Hm, `gcc -fsanitize=address` makes it print `MCHECK_OK` twice. [The code looks simple enough](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/mcheck.c#L93). I would consider writing to some glibc mailing list or one of developers. I believe on `free()` glibc writes something to the memory, overwriting what `freehook` has done. Ex. see [peturb_byte in malloc.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c#L1876).

Comment: thanks, I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed a libc developer mailing list. I split my problem into 2 questions, each of which were responded to:

1. Which manual (GNU or Linux) is correct about MCHECK_FREE?

> They are both correct, but written from slightly different perspectives.
>
> If the block was previously free'd then you should return MCHECK_FREE.
>
> However, if you can't detect that it was previously free'd because of
> corruption then you might only be able to return MCHECK_HEAD as the
> default results if the corruption has changed all co-located metadata
> about the state information.

2. Is it reasonable to generally expect that MCHECK_HEAD will be returned [when calling mprobe on a freed pointer]?

> Yes.